# Fill some place in the picture with users avatar picture

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I would like to set up a bot on discord (js) that could fill some place in the picture with users avatar picture.
For example: Discord bot "Dank Memer" https://dankmemer.lol/
When I write specific command the bot send me picture where it places my avatar into picture (mostly on someone's head) - in real time.
I tried to find how could I do that, but didn't find.
Could someone tell me how to do it or what should I do to make this.

Answer (score 0):

Dank Memer Bot lists the ImageMagick API on their GitHub page. I am developing a bot right now, and can tell you that this is the API you are looking for if you want any image/GIF manipulation whatsoever.
Specifically, there are two APIs, GraphicsMagick (http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) and ImageMagick (https://imagemagick.org/index.php), and they are compatible with Node.js through 'node gm' (https://github.com/aheckmann/gm).